# Encoding type of HttpClient request in JAVA

Tags: java, json, httpclient

I had following String that I passed on to a http-post-request:

String body =

```
{
  "invoicee": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "company",
      "id": "a62117d6-d324-0ae8-8f69-bb63ada0fee2"
    }
  },
  "department_id": "fba7d16b-a988-0420-894f-444b033ac379",
  "payment_term": {
    "type": "cash"
  },
  "grouped_lines": [
    {
      "section": {
        "title": ""
      },
      "line_items": [
        {
          "quantity": 3,
          "description": "An awesome product",
          "unit_price": {
            "amount": 123.3,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "tax": "excluding"
          },
          "tax_rate_id": "23d7af10-427b-06e4-8242-88e8228cc381"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": "673bfdeb-1112-0423-9e54-a8adace28ae4",
      "value": "Opdrachtbon Kruidvat 8957 365690.01 Kruidvat 8957 Neerstraat 34 Brakel (OVL) De keukenkraan is eraf gevallen, robinet cuisine est tombé "
    }
  ]
}
```

```
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        headers.add("authorization", "Bearer " + acces_token);
```

It returned a 400 bad request with specific info that this was a malformed JSON.

My header contains: "Content-type" : "application/json".

The problem with this was in custom_fields object, within the "value" there was following character 'é'. Replacing this character with 'e' made the json ok and my Reponse-status was 201 OK.

Do you know how I can prevent this in future requests? Do I have to put a specific encoding for my request?

ATM my request looks like this:

```
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);

        try {
            rest.exchange("https://api.teamleader.eu/invoices.draft", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            System.out.println("!!ERROR!!");
            System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());

        }
```

Comment: Your JSON is fine. What exaclty is `body` and what are the `headers` in `requestEntity`?

Comment: see edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the charset in the header

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

This explains it further [W3C Internationalisation](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index)